# Site-to-Site VPN - verificaton

Tags: router, vpn, firewall

I am new to setting up a site-to-site VPN and I just wanted to clarify how you set one up. I'm a little confused at where to configure the S-2-S VPN as several sources say on router or firewall. Do you need to do configuration on both router and firewall? Do you even need a firewall to do it? or can you just configure it between routers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail.  What equipment do you have (at both ends)?  A diagram showing your existing network would be helpful.

Comment: Try to answer the questions below: 1. How many sites are you trying to interconnect? 2. Do you have access to the networking equipment at all sites? 3. You will need either routers or firewalls capable of IPSEC 4. VPNs usually terminate on edge network equipment which usually are your firewall or router. This is known as your VPN endpoint. 5. For each site, identify the LAN subnet which you want to be accessible over VPN 6. Agree on a pre-shared key (secret code/word) to be used on all VPN endpoints. If you can provide us with the make and model of your firewall/routers and answers to the abov

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks so far for your responses. current setup is [LAN]-->[Firewall (Checkpoint)]-->[Router (Cisco 2911)] we want to add a new site and will be getting a new BT line (UK) put in. So would it be best to try and replicate and use the same make/models as the main site? Or as you say as long as it has ipsec capability you can use any device?

Comment: Sure, using identical hardware at both sites might make it a bit easier on you but IPSec is generic.

Comment: but say if i just wanted to use a router at the new site which is ipsec capable with no firewall. I'd still be able to create a site-to-site VPN with my current site by just configuring ipsec on the router at my current site without further configuration to the firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer some of your basic questions:

You only need two devices to establish a site-to-site tunnel.  Very often those devices are routers and/or firewalls.  Especially in small or medium business a device which is really a router AND firewall in one (an appliance) is used.  You don't *need* a firewall per se, but it would be silly not to have one in place on each end of real production sites because a firewall allows you to configure rules to permit only the type of traffic coming from a specific person/place to traverse your private network.

To answer your question about configuring both the router and firewall: Yes, you'll need to build the tunnel and also configure the rules in the firewall to allow the traffic from the trusted site, otherwise your hosts at site A will not be able to communicate to your hosts at site B.  Again, the firewall is often the same device as the router, but both areas still need to be configured specifically for what you're trying to acheive in the end.

The steps for building a tunnel between sites varies depending on what kind of hardware one uses, but a generic description for Cisco is [here](http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/867-cisco-router-site-to-site-ipsec-vpn.html).  This will give you an idea of what's involved.